# MLP model AI with Tensorflow outputs random stuff, need some code verification

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I created a MLP class model for MNIST database learning and an in-class function called ".ask(image_file)" and tested it multiple times with the same file ( .png image file ) but the eval() print different arrays each time in the end, and not close equals either.
Would someone tell me where that comes from and also....
I need someone to verify some of the code, when I use the ask() function, I want to make sure it uses the weights and biases post-training and don't really know if tensorflow modified the Layers weigth ans biases.... Help X)

I've tried changing the original .png file ( which is just a black background with a white number scripted on it ) and also tried giving the AI more epochs to learn better ? I just don't know what to do at this point :'D

Here are the data I'm using and the sigmoid function I use in all the layers :

```py
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
sigmoid=lambda x : tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
```

Here is the Layer class :

```py
class Layer():
    def __init__ (self,n_neurons,n_inputs,weights=None,biases=None,a_function=sigmoid):
        if weights==None:
            self.weights=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_neurons]))
        if biases==None:
            self.biases=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_neurons]))
        self.a_function=sigmoid
        self.n_neurons=n_neurons
        self.n_inputs=n_inputs
    def call(self,inputs):
        s=self.a_function(tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs,self.weights), self.biases))
        return s
```

Here is the MLP class :

```py
class MLP():
    def __init__(self,layers=None):
        if layers!=None and type(layers)==list:
            self.layers=layers
            self.n_layers=len(layers)
        else:
            self.layers=[]
            self.n_layers=0

        self.weights={}
        self.weights_setup()
        self.biases={}
        self.biases_setup()

    def add_layer(self,new_layer):
        self.layers.append(new_layer)
        self.n_layers=self.n_layers+1

    def think(self,inputs):
        data=inputs
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            data=self.layers[i].call(data)
        return data

    def weights_setup(self):
        self.weights={}
        if self.n_layers==0:
            return
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            if i==self.n_layers-1:
                self.weights['out']=self.layers[i].weights
            else:
                self.weights['h'+str(i+1)]=self.layers[i].weights
    def biases_setup(self):
        self.biases={}
        if self.n_layers==0:
            return
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            if i==self.n_layers-1:
                self.biases['out']=self.layers[i].biases
            else:
                self.biases['h'+str(i+1)]=self.layers[i].biases
    def ask(self,fichier,plot=False):
        image=image_translator(fichier)
        print(image)
        image=[image]
        request=tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
        result=self.think(request)
        initask = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        print(type(result))
        print(result)
        with tf.Session() as sessask:
            sessask.run(initask)
            print (result.eval())
        if plot==True:
            plt.figure()
            image=import_image(fichier)
            plt.imshow(image)
            plt.colorbar()
            plt.grid(False)
            plt.show()





    def train(self,mnist, n_epochs,learning_rate):
        X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.layers[0].n_inputs])
        Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.layers[-1].n_neurons])
        learning_rate = learning_rate
        training_epochs = n_epochs
        batch_size = 100
        display_step = 1
        self.weights_setup()
        weights=self.weights
        self.biases_setup()
        biases=self.biases
        logits = self.think(X)
        loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init)

            # Training cycle
            for epoch in range(training_epochs):
                avg_cost = 0.
                total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
                # Loop over all batches
                for i in range(total_batch):
                    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                    # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
                    _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                            Y: batch_y})
                    # Compute average loss
                    avg_cost += c / total_batch
                # Display logs per epoch step
                if epoch % display_step == 0:
                    print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("Optimization Finished!")

            # Test model
            pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
            # Calculate accuracy
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
            print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: mnist.test.images, Y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Here is the functions to import the image, translate it into a numpy array of values from 0 to 255 ( whiteness gradient ) and then normalize it.

```py
def import_image(fichier):
    img = Image.open(fichier).convert('L')
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
    data = list(img.getdata())
    data = [data[offset:offset+WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH*HEIGHT, WIDTH)]
    return data


def image_translator(nom):
    data=import_image(nom)
    image=[]
    for i in range(28):
        for j in range(28):
            pixel=int(data[i][j])/255
            image.append(pixel)
    return image
```

And here is the model script that I use :

```py
Model=MLP()
layer1=Layer(256,784)
layer2=Layer(256,256)
layer3=Layer(10,256)
Model.add_layer(layer1)
Model.add_layer(layer2)
Model.add_layer(layer3)
Model.train(mnist,15,0.001)
Model.ask('Sans titre.jpg')
```

I expected an array with a value close to 1 for the one digit I've drawn on the .png file. but multiple ones are close to 1 and it changes when I try the last line

```py
Model.ask('Sans titre.jpg')
```

What is causing the random part in the results and also is the classes above correct ( meaning are the weights used in the .think() the ones that were changed by the training ? )

Comment: This is much too broad; this is not a code review service. Note that you are re-initializing all variables every time you call `ask`, so you get different (and completely random/untrained) results every time. I would suggest that you review some TF tutorials to understand the correct workflow better.

Comment: So how can I get the value out of the tensor at the exit of .think and print it ? whitout running a session or having to initialize things like you said.

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't create a new session & initialize tings _every time_ you run a prediction. You only do this once and then predict repeatedly. As I said, I think you should review the TF execution model. Alternatively, consider using eager execution where you don't have to worry about stuff like sessions etc.